# AsyncFileUpload in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modal-dialog

I've came across strange issue with *AsyncFileUpload* and file larger than value in:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
```

It is working "fine" in page itself by showing "Permission denied" message and I'm also capable of handling it using *OnClientUploadError* script.

However when I access same page using:

```
window.showModalDialog()
```

my page gets frozen.

Any idea on what could cause this kind of behavior?
Thank you.

p.s. At the moment it is kind a hard to switch to *AjaxFileUpload* or *ModalPopupExtender*, so I really hope there is some way of solving this issue using existing components.

Answer (score 0):

Use [github.com/rgrove/lazyload/](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/) as this is the simple and effective asynchronous css and js file load

Comment: CSS and JS, I don't see support for any other file type.

Comment: I just mentioned that, but for nodeJS flatform use [this link](http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/18359176420/asynchronous-file-uploading-using-express-and-node-js)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using node.js.

Comment: You can use pipeline, which come for different platform, search assets platform for your required back-end.

Comment: In that case I'd rather go with _AjaxFileUpload_. But thank you anyway.